# Unable to import matplotlib.pyplot with latest conda

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, conda

I am running Conda version 4.2.9 with Python 2.7.12, I have confirmed this bug with a fresh conda environment and only the matplotlib package

My problem occurs when I try to import matplotlib.pyplot:

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/me/anaconda2/envs/snowflake/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 114, in <module>
    _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
  File "/home/me/anaconda2/envs/snowflake/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line 32, in pylab_setup
    globals(),locals(),[backend_name],0)
  File "/home/me/anaconda2/envs/snowflake/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5agg.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .backend_qt5 import QtCore
  File "/home/me/anaconda2/envs/snowflake/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5.py", line 31, in <module>
    from .qt_compat import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, _getSaveFileName, __version__
  File "/home/me/anaconda2/envs/snowflake/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/qt_compat.py", line 137, in <module>
    from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
ImportError: No module named PyQt4
```

I have googled this issue extensively and see that there are some temporary solutions, however, I don't know how to use one of them and the other one doesn't work for me.

One solution was to set the backend for matplotlib manually like so:

```
>>> import matplotlib
>>> matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/me/anaconda2/envs/snowflake/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 114, in <module>
    _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
  File "/home/me/anaconda2/envs/snowflake/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line 32, in pylab_setup
    globals(),locals(),[backend_name],0)
  File "/home/me/anaconda2/envs/snowflake/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5agg.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .backend_qt5 import QtCore
  File "/home/me/anaconda2/envs/snowflake/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5.py", line 31, in <module>
    from .qt_compat import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, _getSaveFileName, __version__
  File "/home/me/anaconda2/envs/snowflake/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/qt_compat.py", line 137, in <module>
    from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
ImportError: No module named PyQt4
```

As you can see this failed for me. The other solution was to use a patch ([sourced from this thread](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1068)). Unfortunately I do not know how to use this patch or how to "pin pyqt to 4.11". Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Pinning packages is explained [here](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/faq.html#pinning-packages).

[The patch](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-recipes/blob/master/matplotlib/rctmp_pyside.patch) is so small you can apply it by hand. Look for your [matplotlibrc](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html#the-matplotlibrc-file) file (probably `.config/matplotlib/matplotlibrc`), and set the default backend to Qt5Agg by editing the following lines:

```
backend      : Qt5Agg
backend.qt5  : PyQt5
```

However, since you already have `use("Qt5Agg")` in your program, which overrides the rcfile, I don't think this will help.

I think your issue is caused by having a `QT_API` environment variable that still is set to `PyQt4` (or `PySide`). Check this, for instance, by adding `import os; print(os.environ.get('QT_API'))` to your program. If this is the case, add the line `export QT_API=PyQt5` to your `.bashrc` (assuming you run Linux).